# Is there a way to disable the challenge message when I move a file from iCloud to my local drive?

Tags: macos, icloud, finder

Frequently, I move individual files from iCloud to my local drive.  Every time I do this, I'm asked for confirmation with the prompt "Am I sure" (see pic).  Is there a way to disable this warning?  I find it very disruptive in my workflow.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the advanced settings in Finder Preferences.

"Show warning before removing from iCloud Drive".

> [image]